# Remove and add fields from dropdown based on textfield, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

I want to be able to remove and add fields from a dropdown based on the value (number) in a text box.

I have attempted the following jsfiddle which removes items but I need to be able to add the items back if the value changes and add more conditions.

I also want all the options need to remain apart from when the amount of days is either too great or too little. For example, if the user entered 30 the following would show in the dropdown: 
Brazil 
China 
Portugal, 1 – 6 days 
Portugal, 7 – 28 days 
Spain, 1 – 6 days 
Spain, 7 – 28 days

If the value in the textbox changed to 5 the options 'Portugal, 29+ days' and 'Spain, 29+ days' would be re-added and 'Portugal, 1 – 6 days' and 'Spain, 1 – 6 days' would be removed.

```
    Amount: <input type="text" id="amountofdays"  />
    <select id="destination" name="destination" size="1">
        <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
        <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        <option value="Portugal, 1 – 6 days">Portugal, 1 – 6 days</option>
        <option value="Portugal, 7 – 28 days">Portugal, 7 – 28 days</option>
        <option value="Portugal, 29+ days">Portugal, 29+ days</option>
        <option value="Spain, 1 – 6 days">Spain, 1 – 6 days</option>
        <option value="Spain, 7 – 28 days">Spain, 7 – 28 days</option>
        <option value="Spain, 29+ days">Spain, 29+ days</option>
     </select>
    $("#amountofdays, #destination").change(function () {
    var amountofdaystotal = document.getElementById("amountofdays").value;
    if ((amountofdaystotal) <= (29)) {
       var selectobject=document.getElementById("destination")
       for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){
      if (selectobject.options[i].value == 'Portugal, 29+ days'  || 
    selectobject.options[i].value == 'Spain, 29+ days')
    selectobject.remove(i);

    } 
    }


});
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pele09/xpg6sfga/8/

Please can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to show options in the dropdown whose has equal or greater number of days than the amount entered? What about Brazil and China?

Comment: Hi Joey, all the options need to remain apart from when the amount of days is either too great or too little. For example, if the user entered 30 the following would show in the dropdown:
Brazil
China
Portugal, 1 – 6 days
Portugal, 7 – 28 days
Spain, 1 – 6 days
Spain, 7 – 28 days
If the value changed to 5 the 'Portugal, 29+ days' and 'Spain, 29+ days' would be re-added and 'Portugal, 1 – 6 days' and 'Spain, 1 – 6 days' would be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the entire code Snippet

```js
var list=[
          {place:"Portugal","min":1,"max":6},
          {place:"Brazil","min":7,"max":28},
          {place:"Spain","min":1,"max":6}];

  $("#amountofdays").change(function () {

    select = document.getElementById('destination');
    select.innerHTML="";
    var days = document.getElementById("amountofdays").value;
 
    
    for (var i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
      if(list[i].min<=days&&list[i].max>=days){
         var opt = document.createElement('option');
         opt.value = list[i].place+', '+list[i].min+ '-'+list[i].max+' days';
         opt.innerHTML = list[i].place+', '+list[i].min+ '-'+list[i].max+' days';
         select.appendChild(opt);
    }
   
}
    
});
```

```html
Days: <input type="text" id="amountofdays"  />
<br><br>
<select id="destination" name="destination" size="1">
   <option value="">Please Enter number of days</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think you can make that now, please accept my answer

Comment: I really appreciate and respect your work and want to say thanks again. I just can't see how it answer my questions. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I have worked on, not the most elegant but it seems to work fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/pele09/Lrjrraqs/4/

```
    Amount: <input type="text" id="amountofdays"  />
<br><br>
<select id="destination" name="destination" size="1">

        <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
        <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
        <option value="China">China</option>
        <option value="Portugal, 1 – 6 days">Portugal, 1 – 6 days</option>
        <option value="Portugal, 7 – 28 days">Portugal, 7 – 28 days</option>
        <option value="Portugal, 29+ days">Portugal, 29+ days</option>
        <option value="Spain, 1 – 6 days">Spain, 1 – 6 days</option>
        <option value="Spain, 7 – 28 days">Spain, 7 – 28 days</option>
        <option value="Spain, 29+ days">Spain, 29+ days</option>

</select>


$("#amountofdays, #destination").change(function () {
    var amountofdaystotal = document.getElementById("amountofdays").value;

    if ((amountofdaystotal) <= (6)) {
       var selectobject=document.getElementById("destination")
       for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){

      $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Portugal, 7 – 28 days"]').hide();
      $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Spain, 7 – 28 days"]').hide();
      $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Portugal, 1 – 6 days"]').show();
      $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Spain, 1 – 6 days"]').show(); 

    } 
    }

});


$("#amountofdays, #destination").change(function () {
    var amountofdaystotal = document.getElementById("amountofdays").value;

    if ((amountofdaystotal) >= (6)) {
       var selectobject=document.getElementById("destination")
       for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){

      $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Portugal, 7 – 28 days"]').show();
      $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Spain, 7 – 28 days"]').show();
      $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Portugal, 1 – 6 days"]').hide();
      $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Spain, 1 – 6 days"]').hide();
    } 
    }

});


$("#amountofdays, #destination").change(function () {
    var amountofdaystotal = document.getElementById("amountofdays").value;

    if ((amountofdaystotal) <= (29)) {
       var selectobject=document.getElementById("destination")
       for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){

      $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Portugal, 29+ days"]').hide();
      $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Spain, 29+ days"]').hide();

    } 
    }

});

$("#amountofdays, #destination").change(function () {

    var amountofdaystotal = document.getElementById("amountofdays").value;

    if ((amountofdaystotal) >= (29)) {
       var selectobject=document.getElementById("destination")
       for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){      

     $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Portugal, 29+ days"]').show();
     $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Spain, 29+ days"]').show();
     $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Portugal, 7 – 28 days"]').hide();
      $('select[name*="destination"] option[value="Spain, 7 – 28 days"]').hide();

    } 
    }


});
```